# Is there a way to alter what Construct 2 opens test layouts in?

Tags: construct-2

On Construct 2, when you hit Run Layout, it will run the layour (of course) in Internet Explorer so you can play the game/application you are making. But, I would rather it open it in something else, like Firefox or Chrome. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. On construct2, go to project tab on the right, and select your game name. Then go to Properties tab on the left, and find Preview Browser on configuration settings, there you can change the bowser that will open your game when you hit run layout. Hop that this answer help you.

Comment: Ill be able to test it later today.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, it ended up solving all of the problems I have had with my game (so far).